# gVimrc settings are not working

Tags: vim

I am struggling to set settings for gvimrc, and I need your help. These are what I have covered so far :

1) Typing `:echo $MYGVIMRC` should give the directory to the `gvimrc`. Mine doesn't show anything although `:echo $MYVIMRC` says `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc`

2) I also tried editing `$MYGVIMRC` directly through vim as suggested in http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file, but that didn't change anything

I've set `_vimrc`, and running vim in command prompt has worked well with the vimrc settings, but I just cannot figure out why `gvimrc` does not work?

Comment: What settings are you trying to set?

Comment: What is the output of `:echo $HOME` in Vim?

Comment: `C:User\<myName>` is the output of `echo $HOME` and `echo $VIM` returns `C:\Program Files (86x)\Vim`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (`:help gvimrc`), the recommended place for your personal GUI initializations in Win32 is `$HOME/_gvimrc` or `$VIM/_gvimrc`.

I tested this successfully on GVim 7.3 running on a Windows 7 machine:

- `echo $HOME` returns `C:\users\myname`
- `echo $VIM` returns `C:\Program Files\Vim`
- A `_gvimrc` file in either directory is sourced by Vim and its path is set in the `$MYGVIMRC` variable

Comment: My vim is located under `C:\Program Files (86x)\Vim`, and I tried to `vim _gvimrc` at that directory and to put settings such as `set number` and `set numberwidth=3`, but I see no numbers when I execute gvim. Should I reinstall with 64x version?

Comment: Did you try placing the `_gvimrc` file in the `$HOME` directory? If you run the `:scriptnames` command in GVim is the `_gvimrc` file listed?

Comment: `vim _gvimrc` should be `gvim _gvimrc` (yeah, edit _gvimrc in the GUI vim).

Comment: Placing `_gvimrc` under `$HOME` directory did change the gVim settings, but is there anyway to set vim so that it can locate gvimrc in Program Files rather than at Home directory? I just don't like seeing _gvimrc and _vimrc cluttering my Home directory.